# How can I correctly implement a Spring Data JPA repository method retrieving all the objects related to a list of object? (not to a single one)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a Spring Boot application using Spring Data JPA and I have the following problem.

I have this **EventLog** entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "log")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class EventLog implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude          // Needed by Lombock in "Many To One" relathionship to avoid error
    @JoinColumn(name = "source_user_fk", referencedColumnName = "id")
    //@JsonManagedReference(value = "sourceUser")
    private User sourceUser;

    @ManyToOne
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude          // Needed by Lombock in "Many To One" relathionship to avoid error
    @JoinColumn(name = "destination_user_fk", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User destinationUser;

    @ManyToOne
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude          // Needed by Lombock in "Many To One" relathionship to avoid error
    @JoinColumn(name = "source_wallet_fk", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Wallet sourceWallet;

    @ManyToOne
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude          // Needed by Lombock in "Many To One" relathionship to avoid error
    @JoinColumn(name = "destination_wallet_fk", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Wallet destinationWallet;

    @Column(name = "notes")
    private String notes;


    @Column(name = "timestamp")
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;

    @ManyToOne
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude          // Needed by Lombock in "Many To One" relathionship to avoid error
    @JoinColumn(name = "log_type_fk", referencedColumnName = "id")
    //@Column(name = "log_type_fk")
    private LogType logType;
}
```

As you can see it contains this **LogType** field:

```
@ManyToOne
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude          // Needed by Lombock in "Many To One" relathionship to avoid error
@JoinColumn(name = "log_type_fk", referencedColumnName = "id")
private LogType logType;
```

Then I created the following repository interface:

```
public interface LogRepository extends JpaRepository<EventLog, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {

    EventLog findById(String id);

    Page<EventLog> findByLogTypeAndTimestampBetween(LogType logType, LocalDateTime fromDate, LocalDateTime toDate, Pageable pageable);

    // HERE THE PROBLEM !!!
    Page<EventLog> findByLogTypesAndTimestampBetween(List<LogType> logTypesList, LocalDateTime fromDate, LocalDateTime toDate, Pageable pageable);

    
    Page<EventLog> findByTimestampBetween(LocalDateTime fromDate, LocalDateTime toDate, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Into this repository I have this **findByLogTypeAndTimestampBetween()** method retrieving a **Page** specifying a single **LogType** object as query input parameter (basically it return all the logs related to a specific type of log). It works fine.

Then I tried to create the following **findByLogTypesAndTimestampBetween()** method that take a lkist of **LogType** and have to return the logs related to all the log types in the list.

The problem is that adding this second method, running my application I obtain the following error message in my stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'logRepository' defined in com.easydefi.users.repository.LogRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.easydefi.users.repository.LogRepository.findByLogTypesAndTimestampBetween(java.util.List,java.time.LocalDateTime,java.time.LocalDateTime,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.easydefi.users.repository.LogRepository.findByLogTypesAndTimestampBetween(java.util.List,java.time.LocalDateTime,java.time.LocalDateTime,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! No property logTypes found for type EventLog! Did you mean 'logType'?; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.easydefi.users.repository.LogRepository.findByLogTypesAndTimestampBetween(java.util.List,java.time.LocalDateTime,java.time.LocalDateTime,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! No property logTypes found for type EventLog! Did you mean 'logType'?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    ... 101 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.easydefi.users.repository.LogRepository.findByLogTypesAndTimestampBetween(java.util.List,java.time.LocalDateTime,java.time.LocalDateTime,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.easydefi.users.repository.LogRepository.findByLogTypesAndTimestampBetween(java.util.List,java.time.LocalDateTime,java.time.LocalDateTime,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! No property logTypes found for type EventLog! Did you mean 'logType'?; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.easydefi.users.repository.LogRepository.findByLogTypesAndTimestampBetween(java.util.List,java.time.LocalDateTime,java.time.LocalDateTime,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! No property logTypes found for type EventLog! Did you mean 'logType'?
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:106) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1056) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:360) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
    ... 112 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.easydefi.users.repository.LogRepository.findByLogTypesAndTimestampBetween(java.util.List,java.time.LocalDateTime,java.time.LocalDateTime,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)! No property logTypes found for type EventLog! Did you mean 'logType'?
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:113) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:254) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:102) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    ... 134 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property logTypes found for type EventLog! Did you mean 'logType'?
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:437) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:413) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:366) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:348) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:331) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:249) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:383) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:384) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
    ... 138 common frames omitted
```

What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I correctly define a repository method retrieving all the **EventLog** objects related to all the object into the **List logTypesList** parameter?

Comment: Should be something like `findByLogTypeInAndTimestampBetween` [.query-methods.query-creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring JPA is looking for a property 'logType**s**', as the error shows.

You want to find a `LogType` **in** the provided List.

```java
  Page<EventLog> findByLogTypeInAndTimestampBetween(List<LogType> logTypesList, LocalDateTime fromDate, LocalDateTime toDate, Pageable pageable);
```

Reference:
[Supported keywords inside method names](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

Answer (score 1):

Read the log:

```
No property logTypes found for type EventLog! Did you mean 'logType'?
```

and see your field's variable:

```java
private LogType logType;
```

Change

```
Page<EventLog> findByLogTypesAndTimestampBetween(...);
```

to

```
Page<EventLog> findByLogTypeAndTimestampBetween(...);
```